# Otsu threshold finding returning a value that's way too high

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, image-segmentation

I'm trying to use otsu's method in order to separate the background from the foreground of this picture. I'm doing this by breaking the picture into it's colour components and then finding the threshold values for the green and red components. I'll later decide if something is foreground by seeing if it has a high enough green value, but low enough red value. The problem is that I keep getting thresholds of around 245 which I feel like is not what they should be if you look at my histogram. [image]

I feel like the thresholds should be before the 2 green peak at around 150?

Thank-you

```
def otsu_helper(counts):
    '''
    Does the arithmetic of the otsu method
    :param counts: An array recording how many pixels are in each bin
    :return: A threshold found by minimizing the weighted sum of group variances σ^(2)w(t)
    '''

    # variables for otsu's method
    m1t = 0  # mean prob for first group
    q1t = 0  # prob that a given greylevel < t
    s21t = 0  # variace for the group of values less that t
    tot = 0 #keep track of the total amount of pixels captured to bins so far
    pix = sum(counts)   #The total number of pixels
    print(counts)
    group1 = np.zeros(shape=(256,2))
    #Calculate the mean probability and variances for group1 for all values of t
    for i in range(0,256):
        j = i+1
        bin = counts\[i\]
        #print(i,":",bin)
        tot += bin
        pi = bin/pix
        q1t += tot/pix
        if (q1t != 0):
            m1t += (j * pi )/q1t
            s21t += ( (j - m1t)**2 * pi )/q1t
            group1\[i\] = \[q1t,s21t\]  # Store the probability and variance for later use in finding the sum of group variances
        else:
            group1\[i\] = \[None,None\]
    tot = 0
    q2t = 0  # prob that a given greylevel > t
    m2t = 0  # mean prob for second group
    s22t = 0  # variace for the group of values greater than t
    group2 = np.zeros(shape=(256,2))
    group2\[255\] = \[None,None\] #At threshold 256, there are no values greater than t
    # Calculate the mean probability and variances for group2 for all values of t
    for i in range(254, -1, -1):
        j = i+1
        bin = counts\[j\]   #Because all the values from t+1 to G are summed
        tot += bin
        pi = (bin / pix)
        q2t += tot / pix
        if (q2t != 0):
            m2t += (j*pi)/q2t
            s22t += ((j - m2t)**2 * pi)/q2t
            group2\[i\] = \[q2t, s22t\]
        else:
            group2\[i\] = \[None, None\]

    s2w = 999999999999  # Weight sum of group variances
    t = 0   #The optimal threshold value
    #Calculate the weighted sum of group variances for all values of t and save the minimum
    for i in range(0,256):
        if (not np.isnan(group1\[i,1\]) and not np.isnan(group2\[i:1\])):
            s2wt = group1\[i,0\]*group1\[i,1\] + group2\[i,0\]*group2\[i,1\]
            print(i,":","{0:.{1}e}".format(s2wt, 1))
            if s2w > s2wt:
                s2w = s2wt
                t = i

    return t


def otsu(I):
    '''
    Finds the optimal threshold of an image
    :param I: Input image to find the threshold
    :return:A tuple of values that minimizes weighted sum of group variances σ^(2)w(t) for the red and green channel
    '''

    #Isolating the colour channels and placing them in bins
    red = 256 * I\[:, :, 0\]  # Zero out contribution from green
    green = 256 * I\[:, :, 1\]
    blue = 256 * I\[:, :, 2\]
    #red, green, blue = np.moveaxis(I, -1, 0)
    bins = np.array(range(0,257))
    g_counts,pixels = np.histogram(green,bins)
    r_counts,pixels = np.histogram(red, bins)
    b_counts,pixels = np.histogram(blue,bins)
    print('gt = otsu_helper(g_counts)')
    gt = otsu_helper(g_counts)
    print('rt = otsu_helper(r_counts)')
    rt = otsu_helper(r_counts)
#    return (gt,rt)
#   Creating a histogram of the green colour channel
    pixels = pixels\[:-1\]
    plt.bar(pixels, g_counts, align='center')
    plt.xlim(-1, 256)
    plt.show()
    return (gt,rt)
```

[image: Image I am trying to find thresholds for]

Comment: Yes, you are getting wrong results. Why do you need to implement your own? I’m sure SciPy has an implementation, or you can use OpenCV, or any of many other toolboxes. If you want to roll your own, at least compare your output to one of those implementations’.

Comment: It's required of me for a class

Comment: I suggest you look at the [implementation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method#Matlab_implementation). The algorithm is quite a bit simpler than what you've implemented, as you can compute the mean and variances of the two segments incrementally as you move the threshold up along the histogram.